# Parse MMS Parts Using InputStream from WAP Server

Tags: android, inputstream, mms

After you attach an inputstream to am MMS message on a WAP server, does anyone have a suggestible Java api to parse the message?

Someone may recommend the WMA of JavaMe, but JavaME is not the Java implementation on Android. I have tried using various .jar apis from sourceforge but none of them compile properly when added to the build path.

I find myself very stuck attempting to process an MMS message in an Android app? Any suggestions?

Comment: As I understand, MMS API you're looking for, are not part of the official release. You could try to find the source of com.android.mms.* and use it for reference